# Postgres Query execution time

Tags: postgresql

In the `MySQL` command line interface, when you execute a query it will tell you how long the query took to execute after printing out the results.

In the Postgres command line interface (`psql`) it does not tell you. I know how to configure the logging so I can get the information from logs, but it would be more convenient to have it print to standard output like it does in `MySQL`.

Can this be done?

Comment: It's pointless when many Google hits are answers saying "use Google" - about as useful as a chocolate teapot!

Comment: \timing  --it's fun to talk

Comment: It's one way of a couple. But still, if you tried it and it doesn't work, describe it in your question.

Comment: @dragoste: I think a much better place to start finding information about a product is the manual rather than a search engine.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Use `\timing` as explained by ["How can I time SQL-queries using psql?"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/3148/7788).

See also [the manual for `psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).

If you want *server-side* execution times that don't include the time to transfer the result to the client, you can set `log_min_duration_statement = 0` in the configuration, then `SET client_min_messages = log` so you get the log info in the console.

You can also use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to get detailed execution timings. There's some timing overhead for this unless you use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE TRUE, TIMING FALSE)`, which is only in newer versions, and disables detailed timing to give only an aggregate execution time instead.

[PgBadger](http://dalibo.github.io/pgbadger/), especially when combined with [the `auto_explain` module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html), can provide useful aggregate statistics from log analysis.

Finally, there's [`pg_stat_statements`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html), which can collect handy aggregate information on the running system.

Comment: and how to use the \timing

Comment: @aName: Type \timing in psql console and hit enter. :)
To disabe enter \timing again.

Answer (score 59):

I think that `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` might be helpful to you

Syntax:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE query;
```

Example;

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT  * 
FROM    demotable;
```

Output:

```
"Seq Scan on demotable  (cost=0.00..12.10 rows=210 width=356) 
                        (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=8 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 18.477 ms"
"Execution time: 0.042 ms"
```

Comment: what if there are triggers, this won't work

Answer (score 8):

You can use `\timing` in `pgsql` as follows to have the execution time printed to standard output:

```sh
psql -d db -c '\timing' -c 'select 1'
```

Taken from [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3148/how-can-i-time-sql-queries-using-psql#comment356069_3149) comment.