# How to use pg_stat_activity?

Tags: debugging, postgresql

I'd like to see which queries are being executed on a live Django application, and how much memory they are taking up. I have read that `pg_stat_activity` can be useful to monitor a Postgres database.

I have [looked at the Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW), but I have a very simple question that doesn't seem to be answered there.

How do I actually get started with `pg_stat_activity`? What do I type to use it, and where do I type it?

Comment: You probably need the [pgstatstatements module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html) instead.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

See this closely related [answer for question *"Postgres Query execution time"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17655766/398670).

[`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) is a view in the `pg_catalog` schema.

You can query it by `SELECT`ing from it like any other table, e.g. `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity`. The [manual page you linked to](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) explains its columns.

You'll sometimes find yourself wanting to join on other tables like `pg_class` (tables), `pg_namespace` (schemas), etc.

##### Limitations

`pg_stat_activity` does *not* expose information about back-end memory use. You need to use operating-system level facilities for that. However it *does* tell you the process ID, active user, currently running query, activity status, time the last query started, etc. It's good for identifying long-running `idle in transaction` sessions, very long running queries, etc.

Frankly, PostgreSQL's built-in monitoring is rather rudimentary. It's one of the areas that's not that exciting to work on, and commercial clients aren't often willing to fund it. Most people couple tools like [`check_postgres`](http://bucardo.org/wiki/Check_postgres) with Icinga and Munin, or use Zabbix or other external monitoring agents.

In your case it sounds like you really want [`pg_stat_statements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html), and/or [`PgBadger`](https://github.com/darold/pgbadger) log analysis with suitable logging settings and possibly the [`auto_explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) module.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! So just to cover the real basics.... I should start running my script, then in a new console tab, open a postgres connection to my database, and type `select * from pg_stat_activity` and the various statements will appear. Is that correct?

Comment: @Richard No, only the *currently running* statement. `pg_stat_activity` is a view of what's happening *right now*. Sounds like you want the `pg_stat_statements` extension and/or PgBadger + auto_explain to me.

Comment: Even shorter: `TABLE pg_stat_activity;`

Answer (score 14):

Log into the PGAdmin, select your database and right click on your database.
Then click on Query tool to run your query and run,

```
Select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

It will show you all the stats available and you have permissions to.