# Postgres will not allow new connections, suspended process, waiting error

Tags: postgresql

Environment
PostgreSQL 9.5, EnterpriseDB Postgres installer
Windows Server 2012R2 with Active Directory
Symantec End Point Protection

Symptom:

After about 1 week of running, one of PostgreSQL process (postgres.exe) showed "suspended" in task manager, and I cannot kill it in the task manager ("Access Denied" error message appeared). This "suspended" process was not the master PID as indicated in postmaster.pid file. 
Current live connections still work but one cannot establish new connections. The only solution that I have is to restart the Server 
Other information:

The PostgreSQL service is run under a domain account.
The maximum connection was never reached as it is set as 1000 and we only had about 10 connections.
There was plenty of available memory there. The total memory is 288GB and only 8% was used
There were minimum hard drive activities as it occurred. The C drive where PostgreSQL was installed had about 86GB of free space.
There are additional 4 table spaces that are not on C drive but spread over 4 hard drives. Each of 4 hard drives has more than 500GB of space.
we have been using the same configuration files for years and the same file is also used on a second PostgreSQL server, which does not have the issue at all.
The PostgreSQL logs had something like this when this happened and it continues to produce this warning message every minute or so:

2017-06-28 19:40:21 CDT WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled
2017-06-28 19:41:21 CDT WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled
2017-06-28 19:42:21 CDT WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled
2017-06-28 19:43:21 CDT WARNING:  worker took too long to start; canceled

Comment: are you using multithreads?

Comment: I'm was facing this situation a year ago. In that case, the problem was a banking security app called WarSaw, developed by [Diebold](http://www.dieboldnixdorf.com/en-us/services), that intercepts TCP/IP connections. In short, this was a false-positive virus detection.

Comment: Check pg_stats_activity to see how many connections you have open.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654033/how-to-use-pg-stat-activity