is there a way to get the last query sent using from PHP pg_query_params ? ( in order to debug and see if the text sent was correct )
I use the function pg_query_params (or pg_query).
For debugging purposes I would like to be able to get the lastly sent query (eventually having parameters replaced inside).
Is there a call for that ?

I suggest checking out the pg_stat_activity table for the executed query to see if the text sent was correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654033/how-to-use-pg-stat-activity

Install the extension pg_stat_statements to capture all queries and the stats about each query

I will check and revert

I did it and it does not show the last query

It shows you all queries. Your code knows exactly what the last one was, it just sent it.
